# Wildcard SSL Certificate on Wildcard Subdomain in Plesk - wrong certificate served to browser

Tags: ssl, https, subdomain, plesk, wildcard-subdomain

I have a new Plesk 12 installation. I have configured a domain (example.com) with hosting that also requires wildcard subdomains.

To achieve this I had to create a vhost.conf file with

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

This works and I can go to anything.example.com with no issue.

I purchased a wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.com and successfully installed it.

If I go to https://example.com, it works perfectly and shows the correct certificate, however if I go to https://anything.example.com it tells me the connection is untrusted, when I view the certificate, it shows the Parallels Plesk self certified certificate and not my purchased certificate.

I created a vhost_ssl.conf with

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com:443
```

If I add an exception, then I am taken to the correct place, albeit with the incorrect certificate.

Of course I have executed httpdmng --reconfigure-domain example.com and also tried a full reboot.

In summary:

http://example.com - works

http://anything.example.com - works

https://example.com works with my certificate

https://anything.example.com has Parallels certificate but routes to correct page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about create same directive for nginx?

cat /var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/conf/vhost_nginx.conf
server_name  *.domain.tld;

Actually all this can be done from Plesk GUI:
[image: Plesk domain alias web server]

[image: Plesk domain alias web server]

Comment: Thanks. That was better than Parallels's response on its own forum!